# Displaying the entire number in vb6

Tags: vb6

So I have a program coded in Visual Basic 6 that is essentially Cookie Clicker. when it gets into higher numbers though, it displays "1E+16" and so on. I realize this is what is supposed to happen but is there any way to actually display the full number?

Edit:
The number is being stored as a double.

```
Private Sub timerDisplay_Timer()
    lblClicks.Caption = dblClicks
End Sub
```

is displaying the number and

```
Private Sub cmdClick_Click()
    If currentItems = 0 Then
        dblClicks = dblClicks + 1
    Else
        dblClicks = (dblClicks + (currentItems * 2))
    End If
End Sub
```

is incresing the number.

When the number is "100000000000000" (14 zeros), the label displays the number. but when the number is "1000000000000000" (15 zeros) it'll display 1E+15. i want is to actually display the number and not the "xE+y" format.

Comment: We have no idea how you're displaying the number now, what kind of "number" it is (integer, floating point), or how you need to display it at all. Please post the code you have now that "displays" the value, provide example inputs and the outputs you're getting now, and the desired outlook you'd like to see. You have a program coded now, so you should be able to [edit] your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: Most likely though you'll need to use the `Format$()` function instead of relying on default conversion from whatever numeric type you have to String.

Comment: Like Bob says you probably want something like `Format(x, "0000000000000000000")` - see the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262745(v=vs.60).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263416(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work for you

```
dblClicks = 1E+15

Me.lblClicks.Caption = FormatNumber(dblClicks, vbFalse, vbFalse)
Me.lblClicks.Caption = Replace(Me.lblClicks.Caption, ",", vbNullString)
```